# Simplifying function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I have a question about writing jquery.

I need to run functions with two different class names.
(.menu and .menu_single)
To shorten this lengthy functions, what should I do?

```
 <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.menu').on('click',function(){
        $('.menu__line').toggleClass('active');
        $('.gnav').fadeToggle();
        });
    });
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.menu_single').on('click',function(){
        $('.menu__line').toggleClass('active');
        $('.gnav').fadeToggle();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the handler to both classes, and use `$(this)` to refer to the element that the user clicked on.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.menu,.menu_single').on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.gnav').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```